# Type mismatch in c programming

Tags: c, string, compiler-errors

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

void printlength(char a);

void printlength(char a)
{
    int len = strlen(a);
    printf("The Length of the String %s is %d ", a, len);
    getch();
}

void main()
{
    char a[25];
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter the name");
    scanf("%s", &a);
    printlength(a);
}
```

I just started learning c and stuck in these error.
I am getting both the error

type mismatch in parameter error in c and 
type mismatch in parameter redeclaration

Comment: Stop here, C is not a language that you can learn randomly, get a C book. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Did not your compiler warn you?

Comment: No It just showed the error. Working on the problem now

Comment: @Stargateur sure will get a book.Any suggestion for a good book?

Comment: @user3121023 sure

Comment: 1) Throw away this code. 2) Trap your teacher at the bottom of a deep hole by baiting them there with a MS DOS computer from 1991. 3) Uninstall Turbo C. 4) Download something modern, such as for example Codeblocks/gcc.

Answer (score 2):

I can see one problem straight away:

```
printf("The Length of the String %s is %d ",a,len);
```

`%s` is used with strings, and you are passing a `char`.

And, I can see that

```
printlength(a);
```

And `a` is a char array here, so, you need to change to

```
void printlength(char *a)
```

Additinally, you must get rid of `&` with `a` in your `scanf()`, and to avoid buffer overflows, use

```
scanf("%24s",a);
```

A textbook in C programming very a good to start off, and also take a look at the warnings your compiler is providing you with, those are meant for something rather than avoiding.

Answer (score 0):

For starters according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Format specifier `%s` expects an argument of the type `char *`. So the statement with the call of `scanf` should be written at least like

```
scanf("%s", a);
           ^^^
```

though it is more safe to write

```
scanf("%24s", a);
```

It is supposed that the function `printlength` deals with strings. So taking also in account that the pointed data is not changed in the function its parameter shall be declared like

```
void printlength( const char *a );
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The return type of the standard function `strlen` is `size_t`. So the variable len should be declared as having the type `size_t`.

So within the function there should be

```
size_t len = strlen(a);
printf("The Length of the String %s is %zu\n", a, len);
```

It is better to move the call of the non-standard function `getch` in main.

```
int main( void )
{
    //...

    getch();
}
```